# The type of calculation is based on the value of opt. My code is as below, it does not work

Tags: c++

The type of calculation is based on the value of opt:

- 0: summation.
- 1: subtraction.
- 2: multiplication.
- 3: division.

I dont know what i am wrong that my does not work. pls help point it out.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 
 using namespace std;
 int add(int a, int b) {
     return a + b;
 }
 int minus(int a, int b) {
     return a - b;
 }
 int multiply(int a, int b) {
     return a * b;
 }
 int divide(int a, int b) {
     return a / b;
 }
 void calculate(int a, int b, int opt)
 {
     int (*myfunc)(int, int);
     switch(opt){
     case 0: add(a,b); break;
     case 1: minus(a,b);break;
     case 2: multiply(a,b);break;
     case 3: divide(a,b);break;
     }

     int ans = (*myfunc)(a, b);
     printf("Output of calculation is %d.\n", ans);
 }
 int main() {
     calculate(1,2,1);
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `myfunc`

Comment: You never define `myfunc`, you just go ahead and call things like `add`. Do you mean `myfunc = add`? If so why not just make an array like `{ add, minus, multiply, divide }` and then call functions based on index?

Comment: @tadman Much thank.

Answer (score 1):

@Ori

The correct code mentioning below. I am hoping that it is useful for you.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 
 using namespace std;
 
 int add(int a, int b) {
     return a + b;
 }
 int minus_op(int a, int b) {
     return a - b;
 }
 int multiply(int a, int b) {
     return a * b;
 }
 int divide(int a, int b) {
     return a / b;
 }
 void calculate(int a, int b, int opt)
 {
    int (*myfunc)(int, int);
    int ans = 0;

     switch(opt){
        case 0: {
                    myfunc = add; 
                    break;
                }  
        case 1: 
                {
                        myfunc = minus_op;
                        break;
                }
        case 2: 
                {
                    myfunc = multiply;
                    break;
                }
        case 3: 
                {
                    myfunc = divide;
                    break;
                }
        default:
                {
                    printf("Unknown option \n");
                    goto error;
                }
     }

    ans = myfunc(a, b);
    printf("Output of calculation is %d.\n", ans);

    error:
        return ;
 }
 int main() {

    calculate(1, 2, 1);
    return 0;

 }
```